# Java Implementation of Mathematical Magma Structure (And Eventually Groups, Semigroups, etc.)

Tags: java, math, semigroup, abstract-algebra, finite-group-theory

I am creating a small Java application to play around with certain concepts in group/semigroup theory. I want to create a set of basic classes to represent these mathematical structures.
Below is a very (very) basic interface that could be used to represent a set with a closed operation in Java:

```
public interface SetWithClosedOperation <T> {
   BiFunction<T, T, T> getOperation();
}
```

Here, the set of possible values is represented by all possible values instances of class T could take. The operation (which is inherently closed on the set) is given by the getOperation function.

My issues are as follows:

- this doesn't allow for you to have finite sets unless you use enums.
- if you use an enum as the generic type then there would be no practical way to represent "subsets" under the same operation, as you cannot have a generic type which represents a restriction of a given enum.

Described attempted code is above. I would like a structure with the following qualities:

- The structure has a set and a closed function on that set.
- You can form substructures of a given example of the structure which has a subset of the original structures set.

Comment: Java's type system is not really strong enough to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Samuel, you might take a look at Sage (https://sagemath.org) which has, I believe, an implementation of magmas in Python; perhaps that can be some inspiration. (One of the original motivations for the Sage project was to provide an open source alternative to the software named Magma which is often used for working with magmas.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman unfortunately, that was my suspicion. I might try and do it with a different language at some point.